# I am getting the 500 (Internal Server Error) issue when calling adapter in desktop platform

Tags: angularjs, ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-adapters, worklight-server

When i run the below code I am getting error like returned an error: worklight.js:11988 GET http://localhost:10080/sampleProj/apps/services/api/sampleApp/desktopbrowser/adapters/testt/getFeed?params=%5B%5D 500 (Internal Server Error) can anyone help me   we are using below code :

```
 $scope.resourceRequest = new
 WLResourceRequest("/adapters/Test/procedure3", WLResourceRequest.GET);

     $scope.resourceRequest.setQueryParameter("params", []);
    $scope.resourceRequest.send().then(
    $scope.branchShowSuccess,
    $scope.branchShowFailure
  );

};$scope.branchShowSuccess = function(result) {
 console.log(result);}   $scope.branchShowFailure = function(data) {
console.log(data);
   }
```

I am new to ibm work light we are implementing desktop browser application in ibm work light same code running  in  that android platform in  andriod platform geeting success but in desktop browser not working please any help to me

Comment: 500 is an "internal Server error". So look in the Server logfile to find out where the Problem is

Comment: Internal Server Error means it's a server error. Don't think there is anything related to angular here.

Comment: -jens thank you for  response same code working andriod platform  running but  in desktopbrowser application only not working

Answer (score 0):

Desktop Browser environment in MobileFirst Platform Foundation 7.1 does not support the `WLResourceRequest` API. You need to use `WL.Client.invokeProcedure`.

Comment: thank you Idan,  i want to use for MobileFirst Platform Foundation 7.1 means how to call adapter in desktopbrowser platform

Comment: I provided you the answer to this.

Comment: we are follow the WL.client invokeProcedure but  we are getting error:worklight.js:5379 TypeError: Cannot read property 'adapter' of undefined